# Bootstrap input groups and AngularJS dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In the following example:

```js
(function (angular) {
  var module = angular.module('test', []);
  
  module.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.before = $scope.after = true;
    $scope.profile = [
      { key: 'Prop1', type: 'text', value: 'test' },
      { key: 'Prop2', type: 'number', value: 42 },
      { key: 'Prop3', type: 'complex', value: 15, extra: 1 },
    ];
  }]);
  
})(angular);
        
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="before" />
      Show "before"
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="after" />
      Show "after"
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="prop in profile">
    <label class="control-label">{{prop.key}}</label>
    <div class="input-group" data-ng-switch="prop.type">
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-ng-if="before">before</span>
      <input data-ng-switch-when="text" class="form-control"
             type="text" data-ng-model="prop.value" />
      <input data-ng-switch-when="number" class="form-control"
             type="number" data-ng-model="prop.value" />
      <span data-ng-switch-when="complex">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" data-ng-model="prop.value"
               style="display:inline-block;width:calc(100% - 90px)" />
        <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="prop.extra"
                style="display:inline-block;width:90px">
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-ng-if="after">after</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm using `ngSwitch` to display different content for the various properties based on their model data.  This much is working great.

The first two properties (which just use a simple `input` control), integrate nicely with the Bootstrap `input-group` and get either rounded or flat corners as appropriate whether the before/after parts are shown or not.

The third property (which uses two controls in a containing span), doesn't -- its controls always have rounded corners even when the before/after parts are shown and they shouldn't.

I know that this is because of the way that the `input-group`'s CSS tweaks its children -- it will be trying to change the border of the `span` instead of the internal elements.  Although it might be doing *something* to the internal controls, as they do seem to have non-rounded corners in the middle where they join (which is good).

Is there a way to fix this generically?  What's the best way to correct this?  (Note that in my real code the contents of the `span` are generated by a directive, so I can consider JS-based solutions, although pure CSS may be preferable.)

---

Alternately, if the AngularJS is confusing, an even more simplified example that shows the same basic issue:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Prop</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">before</span>
      <span>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" value="42"
               style="display:inline-block;width:calc(100% - 90px)" />
        <select class="form-control"
                style="display:inline-block;width:90px">
          <option value="1" selected>one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <span class="input-group-addon">after</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Removing the `span` tag around the `input`/`select` fixes the problem, but unfortunately that's not a valid solution (due to the AngularJS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd been puzzling over this for days, but in a mysterious case of "writing the problem down provides the answer", I think I've found it after all.

Adding the following CSS seems to do the trick:

```
.input-group span:not(:first-child) .form-control:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.input-group span:not(:last-child) .form-control:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```js
(function (angular) {
  var module = angular.module('test', []);
  
  module.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.before = $scope.after = true;
    $scope.profile = [
      { key: 'Prop1', type: 'text', value: 'test' },
      { key: 'Prop2', type: 'number', value: 42 },
      { key: 'Prop3', type: 'complex', value: 15, extra: 1 },
    ];
  }]);
  
})(angular);
        
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
});
```

```css
.input-group span:not(:first-child) .form-control:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.input-group span:not(:last-child) .form-control:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<form data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="before" />
      Show "before"
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">
      <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="after" />
      Show "after"
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="prop in profile">
    <label class="control-label">{{prop.key}}</label>
    <div class="input-group" data-ng-switch="prop.type">
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-ng-if="before">before</span>
      <input data-ng-switch-when="text" class="form-control"
             type="text" data-ng-model="prop.value" />
      <input data-ng-switch-when="number" class="form-control"
             type="number" data-ng-model="prop.value" />
      <span data-ng-switch-when="complex">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" data-ng-model="prop.value"
               style="display:inline-block;width:calc(100% - 90px)" />
        <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="prop.extra"
                style="display:inline-block;width:90px">
          <option value="1">one</option>
          <option value="2">two</option>
        </select>
      </span>
      <span class="input-group-addon" data-ng-if="after">after</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

(Leaving this question here in case someone else has a similar problem, or a better solution.)